# Storing the Soap values in raw folder

Tags: android

I am working with web service using soap parser. I need to retrieve the values from the web service and store it in local. I have lot of string values in it.

My question is, how and where to store all the string values in my application.
Like, this sort of storage normally we use raw folder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look @ [Android Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

`Raw` and `Asset` folders are **Read-Only**. You cant modify the contents inside, though you can read it only.

In your case, either you should use `SQLite` database or `SharedPreference` to save your data. Another technique would be saving your data in a file created inside sd-card, but then you should evaluate the feasibility.